# What are some differences between encoding vs content-type in Alamofire

Tags: swift, networking, alamofire

```
 Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: param, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: [content-type: multipart/form-data])
```

In header of request I see that there a field called content-type which can be set as **application/json, application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multipart/form-data**. But the problem is that in encoding param we can also set as `JSONEncoding.default`. Then what are some differences between **encoding vs content-type** in `Alamofire`.

Answer (score 1):

The `encoding` parameter sets **how should Alamofire parse the passed parameters**. For example, if it's set to URLEncoding.default, Alamofire will append the parameters to the URL.

The `Content-Type` header, on the other hand, tells the **web server** what type of content do we want to semd.

From [the MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type):

> The `Content-Type` entity header is used to indicate the media type of the resource.
>
> In responses, a `Content-Type` header tells the client what the content type of the returned content actually is.

Comment: I usually see that people set Content-Type: multipart/form-data for uploading file (**sending file to server**). while you said "type of content do we want to **get back**." Can you explain more?

Comment: @Louis Thank you for the notice, I corrected my answer accordingly. The Content-Type header in a request indicates the type of the file that we send to the server.

Comment: It's so helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

encoding:  for parameter which we sending to server

content-type: for specifying the response type

Comment: I usually see that people set Content-Type: multipart/form-data for uploading file (sending file to server). while you said "content-type: for specifying the response type." Can you explain more?

Answer (score 0):

Since Alamofire is an HTTP request wrapper, it provides a parameter for settings HTTP headers. As described by W3C, HTTP headers define how your request will be handled by server : [W3C' Header Field Definitions](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html).

An additional encoding parameter is available in Alamofire since you have to describe how to format an input response. Briefly, server cannot understand how to process a Swift Array or Dictionary, you need to explicitly write what kind of [encoding](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/10323991876208d196c6d1bf91beeb2ec4383b27/Source/ParameterEncoding.swift#L129-L147) is required. Alamofire provides several solutions to encode Swift object : [Alamofire Encoding Options](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md#url-encoding).

In this way, according to your request method (PUT, GET, POST, ...) you could have an Header `["Accept": "application/json"]` and differents Alamofire encoding options.